# Upsert Statement Deleting Non-Conflicting Data (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, etl, upsert

I am currently attempting to run a function withing Postgres to update my production table from my staging table. I have been able to get the function to run, but not as I intended it to do.

My current goal with the use of this statement is to perform an Upsert, but what is happening is that all the data that doesn't exist within the date range of what's being transferred from staging to production is being deleted. This isn't ideal.

```
INSERT INTO xyz.crimsontwreng 

SELECT *
FROM xyz.stg_crimsontwreng 
ON CONFLICT (date, monitorid)
DO UPDATE SET
  replies = excluded.replies,
  retweets = excluded.retweets,
  mentions = excluded.mentions;
```

Curious to know what I am missing from this function to prevent data from outside the date range being deleted. I have year to date data, and now I just have the last seven days worth of information my python script retrieved this morning.

If it helps my function is setup as such.

```
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE 'sql'
VOLATILE
PARALLEL UNSAFE
COST 100
```

*Appears that this issue might be related to a datetime issue with the date field I am calling.

Comment: An `INSERT` statement will never delete rows.

Comment: Would it be something else then within the way my function is setup? Oddly enough data is being deleted here.....

Comment: just to be sure, are you saying data is missing just because python doesn't find it or have you confirmed this by other means?

Comment: Within the table that I am trying to pass data to there's year to date data. I had confirmed this prior to running my Python script which executes a function within our Postgres instance to transfer data from our staging environment to our production environment where that year to date data did sit. 

The staging table contained data retrieved from our source for the last seven days. Upon executing this script yesterday the function completed. I ended up with just seven days worth of data within the production environment.